# Why has an indicator of the close votes remaining number been added

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I have just noticed that now the close votes for a question are displayed in the format: `close (3/5)` Why has this been added? Isn't a question always closed after the 5-th close vote? If that is the case this indicator would be obsolete as the second value will always be the same. Or has some other new functionality been added?

Comment: @Mysticial `pandit` what do you mean?

Comment: I hate typing on an iPhone. The auto correction sucks.

Comment: Before it was ambiguous: 3 votes needed or 3 votes cast.

Comment: Aren't the required number of close votes (and votes in general) different for different sites?

Comment: @J.Steen are they? If that is the case that would answer the question.

Comment: Delete votes can be anywhere from 3 to 10 and it uses the same interface.

Comment: @Mysticial I believe this has only changed recently - in the last week for instance. Before that only close votes remaining used to be displayed.

Comment: Well yeah. But before you wouldn't know how many delete votes something needed. And my guess is that the close-vote and delete-vote buttons share the same interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have a few small changes to this stuff planned:

- The close confirmation was changed to be a blue disappearing pop-up instead of a red persistent one
- We added the /5 to be a little more friendly to users who perhaps aren't aware of the internal workings of the close system.  And why not be explicit when we have the room.
- The link will gray out and be not clickable if you have already voted to close (this is currently not possible because it needs another query), and we will make this consistent for flagging and deleting
- we're going to make this behavior persistent so that when you return to the page it remembers that you voted to close.

  If you forget and want to know how you voted, we altered the tooltip to show this information.

Comment: Knowing I've already cast a vote without having to try to cast it (bullets three and four)! I love it! Praise Atwood and pass the mod flags!

Comment: FYI, because of some technical limitations and space constraints, we're going to be removing the /5 from the close (3/5) link. We may come back to it when we do a bigger refresh of this page.

Answer (score 3):

A fundamental presmise of information, and information technology, is that better information enables better decisions. In this case, a little white space has been exchanged for a definitive statement of progress, without readers having to seek confirmation of either the type of post, or of an unchanged interface. I see this as definite (though  minor) progress for a nearly zero cost.

Comment: I'll note I've been asked at least twice how many reopen votes it takes to reopen a question. I'm not sure why but it seems like that's less common knowledge than how many to close. But showing the count off the bat eliminates any unknowns.